# Mac sandbox created but no NSUserDefaults plist

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, sandbox

I'm trying to track down some issues arising from sandbox creation.  Under multiple circumstances it appears that an NSUserDefaults .plist file is not created in Data/Library/Preferences.  I have seen this in the debugger and when launching the app from the Applications directory.  I have not tried archiving, signing the app and then launching.  Is that required?

An alias file ending in .LSSharedFileList.plist is created but it points to itself and therefore does not exist.

I don't know if it's related but Console reports:

```
appleeventsd[72]: <rdar://problem/11489077> A sandboxed application with pid ... checked in with appleeventsd, but its code signature could not be validated ( either because it was corrupt, or could not be read by appleeventsd ) and so it cannot receive AppleEvents targeted by name, bundle id, or signature. Error=ERROR: #100013  { "NSDescription"="SecCodeCopySigningInformation() returned 100013, -." }  (handleMessage()/appleEventsD.cp #2072) client-reqs-q
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could this be related to the caching of `NSUserDefaults`?

In recent OS X versions the defaults are not immediately written to disk so you might not see them right away. You might want to try synching the prefs manually -
From [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> At runtime, you use an NSUserDefaults object to read the defaults that
>   your application uses from a user’s defaults database. NSUserDefaults
>   caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults
>   database each time you need a default value. The synchronize method,
>   which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the
>   in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.

Although I believe even that might not immediately write the defaults to disk in 10.9 anymore as some daemon caching the user defaults is now also involved.

**Check also**

[Reading NSUserDefaults from helper app in the sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014417/reading-nsuserdefaults-from-helper-app-in-the-sandbox)

[Objective-C NSUserDefaults caching prevents another app from accurately reading changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667848/objective-c-nsuserdefaults-caching-prevents-another-app-from-accurately-reading)

[When (not) to abuse NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520797/when-not-to-abuse-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: Also if you move the container while testing / debugging to the trash, the cfprefsd (see Activity Monitor) still keeps a link to the .plist. Empty the trash and force quit both cfprefsd (user and root).

Comment: Had the same issue with XCode6 and 10.9.5 and after killing cfprefsd everything worked as expected again - so thank's greg - saved me a ton of headaches

Comment: On El Cap I had to reboot; same situation and symptoms though.

Comment: @mahaltertin You are my hero! Thanks for that hint!

Comment: I have used solution given by @mahaltertin. And it works completely fine on my pc. But still, the app has been rejected because when they tested my app, the app is not saving NSUserDefaults value on their mac. So what should I do?

Answer (score 8):

Just moving this into a full answer so it doesn't get missed.  I  only read it after  trying the other solutions when this was solved in a few clicks.

@greg and @mehals answer in the comments section for the first solution solved it for me without needing to change any of my code

> Killing cfprefsd did the trick from activity manager.

Comment: Could anyone explain what this solution actually doing for detail? Or why use this solution? Please. Any Reply will be appreciated.

Comment: @stanliu In my case I was testing the app and deleted the sandbox container folder. I got errors about "accessing preferences outside an application's container", which I think it was just cfprefsd getting confused about why the prefs files it wanted were no longer there.

Answer (score 3):

After spending a ton of time found freaking simple solution:

```
- (void)fixDefaultsIfNeeded{
    NSArray *domains = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    //File should be in library
    NSString *libraryPath = [domains firstObject];
    if (libraryPath) {
        NSString *preferensesPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Preferences"];

        //Defaults file name similar to bundle identifier
        NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

        //Add correct extension
        NSString *defaultsName = [bundleIdentifier stringByAppendingString:@".plist"];

        NSString *defaultsPath = [preferensesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:defaultsName];

        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:defaultsPath]) {
            //Create to fix issues
            [manager createFileAtPath:defaultsPath contents:nil attributes:nil];

            //And restart defaults at the end
            [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was about to say isn't there an NSPreferencesDirectory definition but I checked and there isn't.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this on 10.10 when I trashed the container directory of my app but *didn’t empty the trash*.

On 10.10, I can consistently recreate the app’s property list file not getting created if the container directory is still in the trash and it getting created successfully if the trash is empty.

So, the solution (at least for my issue) is to always empty the trash after deleting the container directory of a Sandboxed app while testing.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2 solution

```
let settingsDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();    

func registerSettingsPlist() {
        let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist");
        let appDocsDirURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory;
        let destinationPath = appDocsDirURL.path?.stringByAppendingString("/Settings.plist");
        if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(destinationPath!)) {
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(appDocsDirURL.path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil);
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath!);
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print ("Error: \(error.domain)")
            }
        }
        let settingsDic = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: destinationPath!);
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(settingsDic as! [String : AnyObject]);
        self.settingsDefaults.synchronize();
    }


lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
            let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask);
            return urls[urls.count-1];
}();
```

Comment: define what `self.applicationDocumentsDirectory ` and `settingsDefaults` means, I assume they are pretty obvious things, but to be totally clear.