# OS X: NSUserDefaults not saved

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I have a sandboxed app for OSX and I saved some data in `NSUserDefaults`, everything was fine until I deleted the plist file from the **~Library/Preferences/** directory.

I thought the app should recreat it but it did not. When I debug I see that

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` method returns `YES`

and data are saved in the class but when I restart the app user defaults is empty.

Even if I copy those plist file from backup to the Preferences directory, the app does not see it.

Of course the plist should be saved in the Containers/my app bundle id/Data/Library/Preferences and when I copy the plist file from backup to that directory, the app can see it, but why that file is not recreated when I deleted it?

Does anybody know why is that?

Comment: I don't understand the down votes. Perfectly legit question. I am also having issues with NSUserDefaults not persisting. I want to test my app launching from a 'blank' slate. So I trash my sandbox container, once I do that NSUserDefaults never persist until I restart the OS. Logging in/out doesn't do anything, only restarting helps.

Comment: Thanks @Brad Goss. I had the same issue after cleaning out my sandbox, debugged for hours, though I was going crazy. Rebooting OSX seemed to have solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Check this question - might be related to **caching** or **prefs location** when running in the sandbox:

[Mac sandbox created but no NSUserDefaults plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242106/mac-sandbox-created-but-no-nsuserdefaults-plist)

Comment: synchronize function should sync cache with database on the disk, so I think there is no problem with caching. Preferences should be placed in the Containers/app/Data/Library/Preferences but this directory is also empty.

Comment: This bit me too. Wiping the Container (while in development) caused all kinds of grief. "defaults delete", etc. couldn't help, and `synchronize` wrote nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, which is caused by deleting the files manually. What you can do instead is to use the `defaults` terminal command. This way I was able to reset the defaults without breaking things. Replace "bundle-identifier" with your bundle id.

To view the current values:

```
defaults read bundle-identifier
```

To remove stored values:

```
defaults delete bundle-identifier
```