# NSUserDefaults does not in Preferences?

Tags: plist, nsuserdefaults, preferences

As everybody know, NSUserDefaults is saved in Library/Preferences.

But....

After I delete com.XXXX.OOO.plist in Library/Preferences/, Xcode still can read Key-Value. Is any other plist at somewhere?

I use Xcode 7.0.1, OS X Yosemite...

Comment: A longer explanation is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242106/mac-sandbox-created-but-no-nsuserdefaults-plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried command

```
defaults delete com.XXXX.OOO.plist
```

or

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.XXXX.OOO.plist
```

But....  it does not work immediately..
It has to kill cfprefsd process to refresh NSUserDefaults

```
killall cfprefsd
```